# jquery cycle plug in not translating to wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cycle

I have a working website that i am translating over to a WordPress theme.  `jquery.cycle.js` works great.  However I can't seem to get it working in WordPress.

1. call jquery (already called in WP)
2. call `cycle.js` (registered, enqueued, and seems printed out as it should when viewing source.
3. have the little script in the head

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.slideshow').cycle({
           fx: 'fade' 
       });
   });
   ```

I have also tried putting this in it's own `.js`  --- but no luck with that yet....

Have a little `img` list holding place from the cycle demo.... in a `div` with the class `.slideshow`

Everything works fine in the original HTML layout.  So I just keep going over this list...

All of the things show up in WordPress when I view source.  anyways.  none of my jquery stuff is working.  I think that if I can get some help with this one thing... it will explain what I am doing wrong.

Getting this... so I guess some of my scripts are using `$` and some jQuery --- gotta get some unity going on here...

[image]

http://www.pauljoyceuk.com/codex/2011/jquery-is-not-a-function/

SO found this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

change to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

this is easy enough with small files...

but what about big files...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
```

if you pass the `$` ---- then eveything seem to work great - without having to change all of them... however - now even though things seem great... I have a whole new host of crazy Errors... hmmm

Comment: ok.  so I read something somewhere in a past thread that suggested to change the $ to jQuery.  So as a last ditch effort - I tried that.  and it worked.  so...  new question:  Why do I need to do that?  Is that part of a non-compete sort of thing?

Comment: You must have another library that is conflicting, such as moo-tools.

Comment: hmmm...  I am using underscores staters theme for the first time.  I see no mention of any other javaScript libraries.

Comment: Just your Firebug for any errors, or view 'Net' tab to see what is loading (As opposed to reading the source).

Comment: ok - so the second example above... passing the dollar sign to function over-rides no-conflict mode... and well... it does things that I don't understand and make me sad.  SO --- I changed every single $ to jQuery... don't miss any !    and now I have a happy litte check in my developement bar... and all of my stuff is working... thanks you 2 for both brining things up that led me to this answer.  !!!

Comment: the really magic answer would be something I could lay in my function.php that would make this a non issue from the start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress's packaged jQuery defaults to [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, use `jQuery('document')`, or wrap your code like

```
(function($) { 
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
})(jQuery);
```

or in your document ready like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Comment: nice and concise answer.  unlike my question.  this is working nicely.